# Building boost fail checking out submodule libs/context

Tags: c++, git, github, boost

I'm trying to build boost using the git repo (https://github.com/boostorg/boost) with the commit (5ec478a570bdc71c5d4854e7165a8b3f4fa82ad9) on Windows.

I created a CMakeFile, and until few days ago, everything was working well. I didn't modify anything since then, but now it fails when checking out submodule libs/context:

```
Cloning into 'libs/context'...
1>CUSTOMBUILD : error : no such remote ref 2ddbe4c26813134cdf8f0d169f70cd85f44b637b
1>  Fetched in submodule path 'libs/context', but it did not contain 2ddbe4c26813134cdf8f0d169f70cd85f44b637b. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
1>  CMake Error at Boost-prefix/tmp/Boost-gitclone.cmake:83 (message):
1>    Failed to update submodules in:
1>    'C:/Users/Me/Project-build/Libraries-build/Boost/boost'
```

I checked the commit in libs/context, and it seems to be there:

https://github.com/boostorg/context/commit/2ddbe

I'm not very familiar with the submodule structure of git, so I'm not sure what is going on. I fixed the boost git tag to always use the same version (which was working for me), so I don't understand why it's not working anymore.

Thank you.

Edit: Does anyone has the same issue (is it coming from the repo?), or is it something coming from my configuration?

Comment: Hmm, are you actually trying to build boost using CMake as a git submodule of your own project?

Comment: No, I use CMake to download and build boost as an external project, and link it to my project. But boost itself, is build with several submodules, which are downloaded and build at compile time. However, for some reason, now the cloning of the submodule libs/context in boost doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can someone properly compile it on Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted boost developers, and they confirmed something was wrong in the repo. They now have fixed it.